# devices have wifi connection but no internet

Tags: networking, lan, wifi-configuration

I have a reoccurring problem:

only for WiFi connected devices (wired works fine).
WiFi signal is good (both over 2.4 or 5 GHz).
devices have WiFi connection but no internet connection.
problem happens multiple times every day.
For each device problem is solved by disconnecting from the network and reconnecting. That indicates to me some kind of timeout on the connection or issue with reconnecting after an accidental signal loss.
Didn't find any useful configuration on my router or any hints online.

Router is a D-Link DIR-2150, most devices have a static local IP.

Comment: 1. Does the issue happen if you allow dynamic IP? 2. Had a similar issue where specifying DNS server (e.g., Cloudflare, 1.1.1.1) failed, but allowing auto DNS resolution worked.

Comment: I am using auto DNS. I can try using dynamic IP but it is not a good solution for me unless maybe I can assign local dns names. Any specific reason why you think it can fix the issue?